# Calculate number of calls to function (not explicitly)

Tags: r, function

I need to calculate number of calls to a function and use it in the function, but not explicitly. E.g. example:

```
f <- function(i,ncall) {
 print(paste("call to function number", ncall))
 i = i^2
 return(i)  
}

print(f(3,ncall=1))
print(f(4,ncall=2))
```

I would like to do the same, but not supplying the `ncall=N` in `f(a,N)` every time. There's no cosmic purpose for this, just wondering if it is at all possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this better?

```
ncall <- 1
f <- function(i) {
  print(paste("call to function number", ncall))
  i <- i^2
  ncall <<- ncall + 1
  i  
}

f(3)
# [1] "call to function number 1"
# [1] 9
f(4)
# [1] "call to function number 2"
# [1] 16
```

Comment: Oh! How simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can set your function to have its own enclosing environment:

```
f <- local({
    n <- 0
    function(i, reset=FALSE)
    {
        n <<- if(reset) 0 else n + 1
        print(paste("call to function number", n))
        i^2
    }
})

f(3)
# [1] "call to function number 1"
# [1] 9
f(4)
# [1] "call to function number 2"
# [1] 16
```

Comment: Best answer an approach for this question.